# File Utils Search Implementation

Tags: java, file, search

I would like to implement a search for files or folders matching a keyword.I am using the following code but the folders returned do not match the string.All the directories are returned.Any ideas what might be wrong please?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

public class SearchFiles {

public static void main(String args[]){
File directory=new File("C:/Users");
String keyword="Logs";
IOFileFilter fileFilter = new IOFileFilter() {
public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
    return directory.isDirectory()&&fileName.contains(keyword);
}

@Override
public boolean accept(File arg0) {
if(arg0.getName().contains(keyword)){return true;}
else{
    return false;
}

}
};
List<File> files = (List<File>)FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(directory, fileFilter, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
for (File file : files) {
    try {
        System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Can you post the code that compiles?

Comment: @Terry Li .Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to javadoc of `FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs`, the resulting collection will also include names of the subdirectories themselves. That is the reason why you see the names of the directories in the result.